# Code for Making copies of file

Tags: c++

I have a file named myfile.txt given below:

```
&cntrl
pTopt = 298.15, pdens = 0.997, prcut = 12.0, pion = t,
pihot = t, prQM = 5.5, prSM = 5.3, prQI=3.0, piguess = f,
pinit = t, pnstep = 5000, pnscale = 100,
pnstat = 5, pnout = 5, pnrst = 5,  pioutc = t, pioutv = t, pnoutc=5,
pnoutv = 5,
msolute = t, nosa = 1,  pichrg = t
gfileOut =   'as-1.out',
gfileEnout = 'as-1.en',
gfileInfo =  'as-1.info',
gfileStart = 'init.in',
gfileRst =   'as-1.rst',
gfileTraj =  'as-1.traj',
gfileVeloc = 'as-1.vel',
gfileQmen =  'as-1.qmen'
&end
```

Using the above given single file I want to create 10 files but I want to manipulate the values of last eight variables in a way that value of the variable in every new file changes as the number of file changes i.e if ten files are created then the value of last eight variables like gfileOut in tength file should be 'as-10.out'.

Comment: Did you intend to include some code?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use C++ for this?

Comment: If you are using C++, look into `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: What language or data file format is your posted code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is simple to write a program which generate desired number of copies of files...

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read template file.
print "\t\t\tWelcome\n";  
print "Enter the number of files you want to generate="
no_of_files = int (raw_input())+1
with open('Assignment.txt') as r:
    content = r.read()

# Write the files.
for i in range(1, no_of_files):
   with open('as-' +str(i)+ '.txt','w') as f:
       f.write(content.format(index=i))
exit()
```